# How to obtain a typical object from each class of my neural network classifier?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, classification

I have trained a deep neural network to classify vectors of a given dimension over 4 classes. Is there a way to "reverse" this neural network in order to obtain what my network considers a typical vector for each of my classes ? In a way, I would like to extract knowledge from my network.

I know that the idea of reversing the network is in a way what is behind Google dreaming machines, but if I'm not mistaken, they are using GAN.